# Jquery plugins for calendar with time zone support

Tags: jquery, plugins, calendar

I need to display calendar for creating schedules in day view, week view and month view

i tried to implement [jquery fullCalendar](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/), every thing is fine but i'm unable to set a default date reference for it. [jquery fullCalendar](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/) plugin takes browser or user system time.

Is there any other jquery calendar plugins which supports different timezones. There should  be a option to set default date time. The calendar should take the given date as reference.

Answer (score 2):

Javascript is the client side language. so it is known to take the time always in local timezone or the users' timezone.

Although, with the hack, we can get the jquery fullCalendar working for different timezones, it will be very difficult to keep track of timezones. It will not be worth the effort. It is a standard practice among the web developers to show the UI always in users' timezone.